# How do you approach optimizing this complex sql query then choosing proper table index's

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, join, indexing

I have a complex query that I can not seem to optimize with proper index's. Any ideas on how to modify the query or index's to optimize. The `columndata` a table has 55000 records, the `drows` d has 4000 records the rest of the tables less than 25 records. How should you approach optimizing a problem like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,
       a.string_data,
       b.grid_id, 
       c.data_type,    
       d.document_id
  FROM  `columndata` a, 
        `columngrid` b, 
        `dcolumns` c, 
        `drows` d  
  WHERE b.grid_id = 9 
    AND d.document_id = 17
    AND d.id = a.row_number   
    AND b.column_id = a.column_id
    AND c.id = a.column_id     
    AND 0 = (SELECT count(1) AS q
               FROM `security` e, 
                    `role_userlist` f,
                    `user_type_defaults`g                                        
              WHERE ((e.access_for = 1 
                AND e.access_for_id = 0)
                 OR (e.access_for = 2
                AND e.access_for_id = f.role_id
                AND f.userid = 0)
                 OR (e.access_for = 3
                 AND e.access_for_id = g.id
                 AND (g.usertype_name =""
                  OR (g.usertype_name = "Guest"
                 AND 0 = 0)))) 
                 AND e.access_level = 0
                 AND ((e.access_type = 2
                 AND e.access_subtype_grid_id = b.grid_id
                 AND e.access_subtype_column_id = a.column_id)                                                          
                  OR  (e.access_type = 4 
                 AND e.access_subtype_document_id = a.document_id
                 AND e.access_subtype_column_id = a.column_id))) 
ORDER BY d.ordering, b.ordering LIMIT 0, 330
```

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE `columndata` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  `document_id` int (11) NOT NULL,  
  `column_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `row_number` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `string_data` varchar (5000),  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),  
  INDEX(`column_id`,`row_number`,`document_id`),  
  INDEX(`row_number`),  
  INDEX(`document_id`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  

CREATE TABLE `columngrid` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  `parent_id` int(11),  
  `column_id` int(11)  NOT NULL,  
  `grid_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),  
  INDEX (`parent_id`),  
  INDEX (`grid_id`,`column_id`,`ordering`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  

CREATE TABLE `dcolumns` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  `header` varchar(25) NOT NULL,  
  `data_type` varchar (25) NOT NULL default 'T',                                                         
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  

CREATE TABLE `drows` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  `parent_id` int(11),  
  `document_id` int (11) NOT NULL,  
  `grid_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),  
  INDEX (`parent_id`),  
  INDEX (`document_id`,`id`,`ordering`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  

CREATE TABLE `security` (    
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,    
  `access_for` int(11) NOT NULL,    
  `access_for_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `access_type` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `access_type_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,  
  `access_subtype_grid_id` int(11) NULL,  
  `access_subtype_column_id` int(11) NULL,  
  `access_subtype_document_id` int(11) NULL,  
  `access_level` int(4) default 0,  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),  
  INDEX `ind1` (`access_for`,`access_for_id`),  
  INDEX `ind2` (`access_type`,`access_type_id`),  
  INDEX `ind3` (`access_type`,`access_subtype_grid_id`,`access_subtype_column_id`),  
  INDEX `ind4` (`access_type`,`access_subtype_document_id`,`access_subtype_column_id`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  

CREATE TABLE `role_userlist` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `userid_assigning_role` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),  
  INDEX (`role_id`),  
  INDEX (`userid`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;  

CREATE TABLE `#__jgrid_user_type_defaults` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  `usertype_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,  
  `access_level` int(11),  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),  
  INDEX `ind1` (`usertype_name`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: most mind boggling query i've seen in ages - lol (sry)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use table [JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) instead of writing endless where statements?
It is not always convenient to fetch everything in single query, as it can decrees overall performance.

for example, I had complex search query which was looking for value in 7 different tables written as single query, it took about 5 seconds to search through 20000 records. After splitting it to 7 smaller queries overall time for such queries was about 0.2 second.

Answer (score 0):

When optimizing a query, first look at the query execution plan that your database engine generates.

Then look first at how many rows you are forcing the poor database to execute, the FROM clause:

```
FROM  `columndata` a, `columngrid` b, `dcolumns` c, `drows` d
```

specifies a join of four tables.  Say, a=55,000 rows, b=25 rows, c=25 rows, d=4,000 rows.  Do the math.  That is 137 **BILLION** rows in the expanded set.  If you are not **ultra careful** about pruning the rows aggressively and **early**, you'll end up with a very slow-running query.

Then look at your WHERE clause.  Without looking at the last clause (which is a large subquery), it seems that you are restricting b to a few rows, and d perhaps to a few hundred rows based on the document_id.  So you're looking at roughly 55,000 x 5 (say), x 5 (say) x 500 (say) = 690 **MILLION** rows.

Obviously your query does not return so many rows, so they all got filtered in the last clause.  However, you last clause in the WHERE clause is a subquery that refers to three more *unrelated* tables.  Which means that you are forcing the database engine to loop through 690 MILLION rows, execute one subquery on EACH (and it is a COUNT query, the slowest kind), and then throw away most of the ones with COUNT <> 0.

Now do you understand why it is slow?

The first thing I can think of to optimize is to replace the `0=(SELECT ...` subquery with `NOT EXISTS (SELECT...` which stops the subquery execution onces a row is found, instead of forcing the database engine to *count* all of them, and *then* checking whether the count is zero.  You have no use of the count.  You are checking for *existence* here.  Use `EXISTS`.

Secondly, make the second query a part of the FROM clause (perhaps a WITH clause or just put in there) and **LEFT JOIN** it together with the columndata table (on the left side), then select (WHERE) on NULL (right side).  This prunes the columndata table (the largest one) by only keep rows that do not exist in the subquery.  A database's query optimizer should attempt to rewrite a subquery with a JOIN, but I am not sure how good MySQL's optimizer is.

Comment: 1. Databases didn't start producing cartesian joins over night just because ANSI joins were invented. Old school joins in the WHERE clause are identical to an INNER JOIN ON(...) unless a specific query shape are matched by legacy code in the optimizer (which is the case in Oracle cbo code base). 2. MySQL doesn't support the WITH clause. 3. MySQL is doing a real lousy job with rewriting semi/anti joins, which means that for larger data sets you have to manually rewrite it using a derived table in the from clause.

Comment: @Ronnis, I didn't make a distinction between ANSI joins and old-school joins with WHERE.  Came from the "old school" myself before ANSI SQL was standardized...  :-)

Comment: me too. Did the switch 2 years ago and never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses. First I removed the recursive call and made it first in my PHP code to find the few column_numbers (integers) that are not to be shown. I then do a "NOT IN" check of the result array. See call below. This call gives this explain result.

id select_type table type  possible_keys   key      key_len   ref        rows  filtered
1  SIMPLE          b   range  grid_id    grid_id      8       NULL       6            1000.00 Using where; Extra Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE    d   ref    PRIMARY      document_id  4       const      4000   100.00
1  SIMPLE    c   eq_ref PRIMARY     PRIMARY       4       b.column_id 1     100.00
1  SIMPLE    a   ref    row_number  column_id     8       c.id,d.id   1     100.00  Using where

SELECT DISTINCT a.id,
       a.string_data,
       b.grid_id, 
       c.data_type,
       d.document_id
  FROM  `columndata` a, 
        `columngrid` b, 
        `dcolumns` c, 
        `drows` d
  WHERE b.grid_id = 9 
    AND d.document_id = 17
    AND d.id = a.row_number
    AND b.column_id = a.column_id
    AND c.id = a.column_id
AND a.column_id NOT IN (0,3,6) 
ORDER BY d.ordering, b.ordering LIMIT 0, 330

I also tried to make a join but this was much slower. Comments on how to improve with proper join syntax would be welcomed

First select rows (4000), then match columns to rows (50000) while removing columns that are hidden, then add extra data from columns and columgrid tables
      SELECT t1.row_id 
       t2.string_data,
       2 AS grid_id, 
       t5.data_type,
       t1.document_id
    (SELECT DISTINCT a.id as row_id,
       a.string_data,
       a.ordering as row_ordering
       FROM  `drows` a
       WHERE a.document_id = 7) t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT b.row_id
                           b.column_id
                           b.string_data
           FROM `dcolumns`
           WHERE b.column_id NOT IN (0,3,6)) t2 ON t1.id = t2.row_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT c.id,
                           c.data_type) t3 ON t2.column_id = t3.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT d.column_id,
                           d.row_id,
                           d.ordering as column_ordering
           FROM `columngrid`)  t4 ON(t1.id = t4.row_id AND t2.column_id = t4.column_id)
 ORDER BY t1.row_ordering, t4.column_ordering